# events in the past: "people who saw" or "people seeing"

Tags: grammaticality

I still have a difficult question in my mind.

Why do we have to write

> - "The police wanted to interview the people who saw the accident"

instead of saying

> - "The police wanted to interview the people seeing the accident"

Thanks so much for spending time helping me ^-^

Comment: Because "saw" is past tense & "seeing" in the present continuous sense.  The accident happened in the past & therefore the past tense is used.  Also, please use a title that relates specifically to the subject of the question; and note that "Britsh English" requires Capital letters.

Comment: The continuous verb form would be more appropriate in a context such as *The police wanted to interview the people **living** near to the scene,* since those people presumably lived there at the time of the accident, ***and*** were still living there later (when the police became interested in seeing them). Clearly those people were no longer still witnessing the event when being interviewed later, so it's not a very logical choice in that exact context. But that doesn't have anything to do with "grammar" - it's just a matter of *meaning*.

Comment: There is no present continuous here - that would be "are seeing". There is a participle "seeing", which has no necessary implication of continuous action, but does imply contemporaneous action, so would suggest that the seeing was at the time of the police wanting them, rather than before that.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing is present tense and so would be incorrect if the police were interviewing the people **after** the accident. The second sentence could also be confused with *"The police wanted to interview the people, seeing the accident"* (implying that the police wanted to interview the people after the police saw the accident).

**Hope that helped**